# Listen emited events of specific child vuejs 2

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, dom-events

The main-template must listen dropdown name is = "dropdown a",
The some component must listen dropdown name is ="dropdown b"...
The main-template listen dropdown b

The main-template

```
<main-template>
      <dropdown name="dropdown a"></dropdown> 
      <some-component>
           <dropdown name="dropdown b"></dropdown>
      </some-component>
</main-template>

Vue.component('dropdown', {
  template: '#dropdown-template',
  methods:{
    selectedItem: function(){
      bus.$emit('selected-item');
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('some-component', {
  template: '#some-component-template',
  mounted:function(){
    bus.$on('selected-item',this.onItemSelected)
    //I want to listen dropdown b
  },
  methods:{
    onItemSelected : function(item){
      
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#main-template',
    mounted:function(){
    bus.$on('selected-item',this.onItemSelected) 
      //I want to listen dropdown a
  },
  methods:{
    onItemSelected : function(item){
      
    }
  }
  
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a bus. Just emit the event and listen to it from the parent.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component('dropdown', {
  template: `<button @click="selectedItem">Emit</button>`,
  methods:{
    selectedItem: function(){
      this.$emit('selected-item');
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('some-component', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Some Component</h1>
      <dropdown @selected-item="onItemSelected"></dropdown>
    </div>`,
  methods:{
    onItemSelected : function(item){
      alert("dropdown b!")
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#main-template',
  methods:{
    onItemSelected : function(item){
      alert("dropdown a!")
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="main-template">
      <h1>Main</h1>
      <dropdown @selected-item="onItemSelected" name="dropdown a"></dropdown> 
      <some-component></some-component>
</div>
```

The above example uses a button in place of whatever you have done for a dropdown, but the principle is the same.

You should only use a bus when there is a specific need. The above snippet should be your *default*. Emit events from your *component*, and listen to those events using `v-on:some-event` (the shortcut for which is `@some-event`).